# Cannot turn in quest fish to terraria angler

Tags: terraria

I went to my angler and he said to catch a long fish that looked like ebonstone and I went to the corruption and eventually caught a fish called ebonkoi, Went back to angler with ebonkoi in hand and tapped him and then... HE GIVES ME A NEW QUEST!!! So annoyed, how to give fish and get reward?

Comment: His offered quest changes every day, so if you wait too long to hand in the fish the quest may change and he won't accept the previous quest's fish any more. Just hold on to it and keep checking back - eventually he will offer that quest again and you can just hand it in straight away.

Comment: @JonK Don't answer in comments

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I only suspect that's what has happened, hence it is a comment and not an answer

Comment: @JonK It reads and feels like an answer, it should be an answer. If you're providing a solution, it is an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the fish is an Infected Scabbardfish. The Ebonkoi is not a quest fish.

Comment: Correct. Quest fish have an orange name - if the fish you caught doesn't have an orange name, it is not a quest fish.